# Convert Excel file with commas to CSV VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a excel file that's need to be converted to CSV by using Excel VBA.

So for I got the following code:

```
Sub REPORT()
    Dim ColNum As Integer 
    Dim Line As String 
    Dim LineValues() As Variant 
    Dim OutputFileNum As Integer 
    Dim PathName As String 
    Dim rowNum As Integer

    'Create CSV file
    PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path OutputFileNum = FreeFile

    Open PathName & "\" & "Myfile" & ".csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

    SheetValues = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        numbercolumns = .Columns.Count
    End With

    ReDim LineValues(1 To numbercolumns)

    For rowNum = 1 To last
        For ColNum = 1 To numbercolumns
            LineValues(ColNum) = SheetValues(rowNum, ColNum)
        Next
        Line = Join(LineValues, ",")
        Print #OutputFileNum, Line
    Next

    Close OutputFileNum
End Sub
```

My problem is when there is a comma in any cell of the Excel file. When this happens the macro divides the cell in two and move one part to the next column overwriting data.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and probably easiest apporach would be to delete all commas before joining:

```
For rowNum = 1 To last
  For ColNum = 1 To numbercolumns
    LineValues(ColNum) = Replace(SheetValues(rowNum, ColNum), ",", "")
  Next
  Line = Join(LineValues, ",")
  Print #OutputFileNum, Line
Next
```

Another option might be to seperate the csv file by ";" or any other char that is not contained within the data used. 
Eventually you could replace the commas by something else (e.g. "#" or other unlikely used chars) and revert this when the file is read, assuming of course the file is read in some way that you have control about.

Comment: But why are there commas in the cells? If this is the decimal separator, then the CSV should use ";" instead of "," between values. If the commas are in strings, values should be enclosed between double quotes. No need to change the actual content

Comment: Hi, if replace "," with "#" how can I revert this in the same when the csv is created ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at native functions?

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=PathName & "\" & "Myfile" & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

It properly escapes cells containing commas with double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method is to enclose the contents you are appending in quotation marks - you can use Char(34).